# primefaces linechart datatip not showing correct value of xAxis

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, linechart

I am facing a problem while using primefaces linechart.

I created linechart `pieChartBean.createPieModel(Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>> piechart)` where X-Axis is displaying `Date`. Now LineChart is displaying correctly but the datatip is not showing correct values. I followed [primefaces example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/lineChart.jsf) to create linechart and found same problem. Here is my sample code:

linchart.xhtml

```
<p:lineChart id="lineChart"  value="#{myBean.getLineChart()}" legendPosition="e" minY="0" maxY="100"  styleClass="jqplot-table-legend jqplot-target">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM.dd.YYYY"/>
</p:lineChart>
```

Linechart Screenshot

[image]

Here datatip is showing `(1,40) instead of (date, 40)`

```
primefaces version-3.4
```

Update:1

Primefaces UserGuide 3.4 describes chart converter as:

```
Charts support converters for category display, an example case would be java.util.Date objects for categories, in case you’d like charts to do the date formatting, bind a converter.
   <p:lineChart value="#{bean.model}">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
   </p:lineChart>
```

How does [jqplot dateAxis](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/date-axes.html#) can help

Linechart accepts data as `Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>>` but according to converter it should be `Arraylist<HashMap<Date, integer>>`. Am I missing something

Thanks

Comment: dunno if it helps http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2180 and http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23891&p=78637#p78637

Comment: I followed both the links but these posts talk about the issue where dates are not displaying on x-Axis. This constraint is removed in primefaces-3.4. I am concern about the datatipFormat. Thanks for reply

Comment: are you sure that `f:convertDateTime` could be used with `p:lineChart` in that way?

Comment: ya..I have read primefaces User Guide 3.4 where linechart supports converters. I have updated my question with its user guide info. PLease check it

Comment: Maybe they did not implemented the tooltip for date to show the date...

Comment: may be...But I uses `pieChartBean.createPieModel(Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>> piechart)`. Logically it should take `Arraylist<HashMap<Date, integer>> piechart` for date convereter. Isn't it..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17487/discussion-between-dipendra-singh-and-daniel)

Comment: I'm not using primefaces charts, to me it looks like they forgot to implement the date thing in the tooltip... (so i don't have anything to say in chat :) )